# Creating a sub-site on GitHub

Tags: github, github-pages, quarto

I have started a blog on GitHub using quarto. It works ok at [this web address](https://juanriera.github.io/blog/).

I am also writing a book using quarto, and I have published it (draft test version) on a different repository, under the subfolder /docs/. Now I want to link it from my blog, with a link on the blog upper bar as you can see in the former link, under the menu option `Libro`. I have configured Pages to serve this book from subfolder `docs` under the book repository, same as blog, but in this case, Pages doesn't say it's serving the site as...

**Repo structure**: 
**blog**: master/blog/docs/ 
**book**:  master/industrial-stats/docs/

However the book repository is not serving the pages as a web page, and I get the error 404. From the GitHub docs, I thought I understood you [can serve a site as a **project**](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites), using GitHub own terms, but I'm not sure how to configure it. As my account is free, maybe I can't have two different sites? does this prevent me having both blog and book on the same address? Can I configure Pages somehow to serve files from another GitHub repo?

BTW, if I cancel the blog site and reconfigure the book repository to serve it with Pages, it works perfectly too, so there's no problem with site structure, I think.

Thanks for any advice,

Comment: Is the book repository public? For free account, you can't publish a GitHub Pages site from a private repo, see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages).

Comment: All repos are public, you can check here: https://github.com/juanriera

Comment: It's very odd, the [build job](https://github.com/juanriera/industrial-stats/actions/runs/4242837550/jobs/7374842226) reports that everything was done successfully... one thing you could try: since you're not using Jekyll, you can sidestep Jekyll doing anything with your files by dropping an empty `.nojekyll` file into the `docs` directory. This reduces the build step to just uploading your static assets, though I'm not sure if that'll fix it. It looks like it should be working already.

Comment: I downloaded the artifact and inspected it locally, everything's there and looks right. Weird. Maybe re-run the job?

Comment: Just reloaded the book site with the `.nojekyll` empty file and now it works! Thank you very much! It's weird that the book was working ok when I configured Pages to serve only the book. Anyway, problem solved!